# Cannot login Yocto qemux86-64

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, intel, yocto

I've generated the iso image successfully. However, it asks me for the login information. 
For "qemux86-64 login", I just leave the username empty and password empty since I didn't create any login passwords when I create the image. It won't let me login. Then I tried username "root", it showed me this:
[Login as root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gec4P.png)

Then I added

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "useradd -P 1234*56 nokola;
```

to **extrausers.bbclass** in meta directory. However, I still cannot login and it showed me "log in incorrect". 
[login as user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xNgA.png)

Is there anything I am missing or getting wrong?

---

I was building Yocto image followed the user manual, however after running bitbake, there's no .iso/.hddimg in the `/home/nikola/yocto_build/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86-64 directory`. (nikola is my username)

Here's the configuration:

1. OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
2. Hardware:
   Intel Atom E3950 processor; 8GB Memory; 500GB HDD
3. Manual: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/release-notes/atom-soc-celeron-n3350-pentium-n4200-bsp-for-yocto-project-mr3-release-notes.pdf?asset=14076

[image: There's no iso/hddimg file after running bitbake]
[image: Yocto Project]

Comment: Please, what are you asking?

Comment: Search for "IMAGE_FSTYPES" in the manual. Also, try searching for "hddimg" in the manual. There is plenty of documentation on this process.

Comment: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-IMAGE_FSTYPES

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in  your `build/conf/local.conf` file and compile again then it will come.

```
IMAGE_FSTYPES += "iso"
```

for more images types click the link [yocto-image-types](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-IMAGE_TYPES)

Comment: Hi, I've generated the iso image successfully. However, it asks me for the login information. For "qemux86-64 login", I just leave it empty and password as empty since I didn't create any login passwords at the beginning. It won't let me login. Then I added                                       "inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "useradd -P 1234*56 nokola;" to extrausers.bbclass in meta directory. However, I still cannot login and it showed me "log in incorrect". Is there anything I am missing or getting wrong?

Comment: remove "*" in your password and try once

Answer (score 0):

nikola said

> Then I tried username "root", it showed me this (png image)

In that png, 2nd line in red shows that the login (root, no password) did actually succeed. root@qemux86-64:~#

You could enter commands there e.g. whoami or "ls -lt /", they will execute.